# How to I create a data frame from inbuilt data set 'iris'?

Tags: r

I am a beginner at using Rstudio and have been working through the exercises outlined as part of our course notes.
We are to work with the 'iris' dataset however I haven't been able to successfully save it as a valid data.frame.  The best I have done is created an empty dataframe in the global environment with 0 obs. of 0 variables.

Here is some of the codes I have worked through and the outputs.  I am very new to R and am struggling a little with using inbuilt data sets in terms of loading and using - I am ok with importing and creating however.

```
data()
> View(iris)
> iris<-write.csv(iris)
""
> iris
NULL
> str(iris)
 NULL
> iris<-data.frame(iris)
> iris<-read.csv(iris.csv)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  object 'iris.csv' not found
> library(datasets)
> data.frame(iris)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

I have tried > write.csv(iris, 'iris.csv') # no luck

Comment: `write.csv(iris, 'iris.csv')`?

Comment: If you run the line `data(iris)` then you can access the data frame by typing `iris`.

Comment: Restart your R session and type `iris` in the console.

Comment: You can export `iris` as a comma separated text file using `write.csv()`. If you want to save `iris` as a data frame (which is a data structure that only R can read), use `save(iris, file="iris.RData")` and then load it with `load("iris.RData")`. You use `write.csv()` to save the file in a format that can be read by spreadsheet and database programs. Using `write.csv()` can cause a loss of information since factors cannot be written and you may have compatibility problems with time/date data.

Answer (score 0):

First check if iris is already a `data.frame` by running the following command:-

`is.data.frame(iris)`

If the answer is `TRUE`, then run in the following command to write it to a `.csv` file:-

`write.csv(iris, "/location/at/which/you/want/to/save/the/file)`

If one wants to save objects as R objects, one has to use `save()` and the file extension has to be `.RData`. Like in you case you can run the following command:-

`save(iris, file = '/location/iris.RData'`

And you can load an `.RData` file with the `load()` function in R. In your case it could be :-

`load('/location/iris.RData')`

**Some mistakes that you've made:-**
In your second code line where you run

`> iris<-write.csv(iris)`

you've just provided `write.csv` with it's first argument called `x`, but never specified the second argument it requires which is `file`. And also, one never assign `write.csv()` function with it's arguments to an object with the help of `<-` because `write.csv()` is a function which does not returns a value or an object. Another example of a function like `write.csv()` could be `library()`.

So the way you code flows is you worte a wrong syntax for by running the following line

`> iris<-write.csv(iris)`

and hence, you got a `NULL` object. And the `str` of a `NULL` object is itself `NULL`.
Then you created a `data.frame` objects by passing `iris` as a data object, but since earlier `iris` became a `NULL` object, `data.frame` of a `NULL` object is `NULL`. Since there never was an `iris.csv` file written, R won't be able to read it too.

Also in your `read.csv()` function, you passed the `file` argument as a data object and not as a path. This is why you got the error `object 'iris.csv' not found` and not as `cannot open file 'iris.csv': No such file or directory`. To pass it as a path you should always put the location of your file in quotes, either single or double.

If you ever you don't understand how you have to pass objects in a function, please run the command `?function_name`, for example `?write.csv()`, `?library`, `?read.csv`. This will provide you with documentation on the function. It will also provide you with usage examples.

I hope this helps.